# Sending SMS for a bulk of users

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, sms, httpwebrequest

I want to send `SMS` to bulk of users(4000 user) so i put the following method on loop :

```
protected int SendSMS(string url)
        {
            // Now to Send Data.

            StreamWriter writer = null;
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            Uri myUri = new Uri(url);
            postData.Append(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("Username"));
            postData.Append(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("Password"));
            postData.Append(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("Sender"));
            postData.Append(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("Recipients"));
            postData.Append(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("MessageData"));



            string webpageContent = string.Empty;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());


            try
            {
                using (Stream webpageStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }

                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        webpageContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        //TODO:parse webpagecontent: iF response contains "OK"
                        if (webpageContent.Contains("OK")) return 1;
                        else return 0;
                    }
                }
                //return 1;

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                ErrMapping.WriteLog(url);
                string error = ee.Message + "<br><br>Stack Trace : " + ee.StackTrace;
                ErrMapping.WriteLog(error);
                return -1;
            }

        }
```

---

After a specific number of users like 65 user, no `sms` had been sent for the rest of users and

I get the following exception :

```
Error Message:Thread was being aborted.<br><br>Stack Trace :    at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at SendSMS_EmailUI.Frm_SMS_send.SendSMS(String url)
```

Comment: Simply the Server aborted the Query, try to look if the Server is Highloaded when sending SMSs, Good luck!

Comment: Who is the SMS provider? Could you also post the code for the loop?

Comment: @nmat : Simply i call the previous method in a for loop ( the number of users) whom i want to send the sms.

Comment: Most SMS over HTTP providers will permit you to send the same message to more than one recipeint in a single call, its much more efficent for you and them.

Comment: Why do you get 2 instance of webRequest.GetRequestStream()?

Comment: ... and remember to dispose all IDisposable objects.

Comment: How are you calling that method to send the SMSs? Is it in a desktop app or a web app? The exception looks like a thread abort exception which means the process that was looping was killed, which might happen if it's a web app

Comment: It 's a web application ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have built an SMS portal. What you describe was also experienced in v1.0 of my application. The solution was to have my SMS gateway provide me with Bulk SMS access via HTTP. I could put up to 1000 destinations into an XML (or comma delimited) package and send to the Bulk SMS Gateway. Because I run on a shared host, I limited this to 500 destinations.

I have a cache/temporary storage/table where I batch large destination (up to 1,000,000) in some cases and a scheduler (timer based) sends each batch of 500 every few seconds (by calling a script repeatedly) until the messages are sent. Works like charm!

For personalized messages, I encourage the client to use my desktop application for personalization before forwarding to my SMS portal. Good luck

**PROCESS:**

You'll need three items

1. The Script that receives the SendSMS request
2. The script that sends the SMS
3. The Scheduler/Timer (Script/Host Service)

A. The Send SMS request arrives with

```
a. The Message and Sender ID/ Sender GSM Number.

b. The Destinations (as a comma delimited list). We'll assume 10,000 destinations
```

B. Split the destinations into 500 (any size you wish) and log the 500 destinations along with the message and SenderID in each INBOX row/record.
    ***Note: if you count 500 out by looping (10,000 loops), the script could Time out. GSM Numbers in My country are 13 digits. 
    So I do a loop Sub String of length 500*(13+1) to get 500 destinations per batch (20 loops).***

C. Call the Script that Sends the SMS. Sends the first 500 and tag the message as Sent. You can add Time Sent. Start the Scheduler

D. The Scheduler checks every 1.5 minutes if any unsent messages exist in the INBOX and sends it. If nothing, Scheduler Stops.
    So, 10,000 messages are sent within 30 mintues

Comment: Could u explain more please , with an example ?

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, the bulk operations that will be performed on behalf of the application can be done easily by the following procedure

1. When a bulk SMS is triggered, the details will be entered in a database table
2. A windows service will be constantly monitoring this table for any updates
3. When the windows service finds the new entries, it will take few records like few hundreds and then send them. Batch Processing.
4. There can be a delay between consequent requests.
5. This will ensure you to track which line items have failed and also does not clog the server with the bulk data.

This is a most widely suggested approach.

Please provide your comments on this implementation.

Answer (score 5):

We do something similar to what saravan suggested for email messages, and suspect it will work SMS.

Basically the service that runs on our web server only sends x at a time, and there is a custom delay y between each send.
It can send two thousand in less than ten minutes with neither a CPU nor a bandwidth spike.

Some tips that weren't in our original design to keep in mind:

1. Have a way to manually stop all sending (see next tip)
2. Have a user friendly way to terminate a particular message. If your code (or the user) accidentally sends the same thing five times, you want a way to abort it, quickly.
3. Use a config file for both numbers (x & y above) so you can adjust without redeploying. I think the y delay is 50 ms.

Before you decide to bundle the same message to multiple recipients, make sure that smartphones can't reply to everyone else in their bundle.

HTH,

-Chris C.

Comment: Hi Chris,
As mentioned in the tip [3], we have the x & y from the configuration files and that there is no requirement for redeployment. 
We do have a mechanism in place that can get the failed ones sent from the service and then to show to the user so that he can opt for  giving the failed ones a second shot.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the problem is that because you are on an asp.net website and this is a long-running task that it is timing out the response.

this timeout is controlled in the web.config and it's default is set to 110 seconds. Increase this to a much longer number and see if it starts working.

```
  <system.web>
    <!-- 600 seconds = 10 minute timeout --->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
  </system.web>
```

A better approach would be to using a separate thread and returning updates of the progress 
to the user, although this would be more complex, but ultimately more reliable.

See [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx) for a simple way to thread this process.

[Msdn - httpRuntime documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This is not answering your original question, but is related useful info. Once you solve this problem, you may hit another -- telcos routinely block bulk-sent SMS messages as a way to suppress SMS spam. If you will be doing this on a commercial scale, you will need to file a brief with the Mobile Marketing Association, and get their approval, which can take a considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

check if your StreamWriter is getting disposed

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

May be the buffer value is full please check it and put it to maximum value in web-config file

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your are making web request too fast: try slowing them down to rule out timing problems, for example adding a sleep:

```
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

1000ms = 1 sec is only a hint, you should try different values to see if something changes